# Is there something similar to Delphi's String Grid in Tkinter/Pyqt?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, delphi, tkinter, pyqt

I am trying to find something similar to `Delphi's` string Grid, I haven't found something similar in `Tkinter`, it should look like this :

[image]

Comment: check [`Treeview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wxpython` grid cell might be what you are looking for, take a look here :

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/grid_overview.html